# Files\spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7\bin\..\conf] was unexpected at this time

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying to configure the variables on a computer and I'm getting this error whenever I try to run pyspark: Files\spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7\bin..\conf] was unexpected at this time

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same error, and the problem was in a white space.

I was putting the spark folder on this path "C:\Users\myuser\Aplication Data\" so the final path was "C:\Users\myuser\Aplication Data\spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7"

I think you are putting the spark folder on "C:\Program Files\spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7" and in some point the path is being sliced to "Files\spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7".

Try putting the folder in another path without whitespaces.

Hope this helps.